# jQuery to count over images in a div and tell me what image I am currently viewing based on z-index and title attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, orbit

I'm working with the [Orbit jQuery slider](http://www.zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider). Tricky thing is that I am running six iterations of that slider on the page. What I want it to do is tell me I am on image 4 of 7, 5 of 7, etc...

Here's what I've done so far:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var n = $('#dicks-feature img').size();

    $('#dicks-feature img').each(function(index) { 
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        var z = $(this).css('z-index');

        function stuff() {
            if (z == 3) {

                $('<p>' + title + 'of' + n + '</p>').appendTo('.count');
            }
        }

        setInterval(stuff,3000);
    });     

});
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="dicks" class="item first">
        <div id="dicks-feature" class="feature">
            <img src="img/features/DSG/dicks.jpg" width="711" height="369" alt="Dicks Sporting Goods" title="1"/>
            <img src="img/features/DSG/DSG_Primary_1.jpg" width="711" height="369" alt="Dicks Sporting Goods" title="2" />
            <img src="img/features/DSG/DSG_Primary_3.jpg" width="711" height="369" alt="Dicks Sporting Goods" title="3"  />
            <img src="img/features/DSG/DSG_Primary_4.jpg" width="711" height="369" alt="Dicks Sporting Goods" title="4"  />
            <img src="img/features/DSG/DSG_Primary_5.jpg" width="711" height="369" alt="Dicks Sporting Goods" title="5"  />
            <img src="img/features/DSG/DSG_Primary_6.jpg" width="711" height="369" alt="Dicks Sporting Goods" title="6"  />
            <img src="img/features/DSG/DSG_Primary_7.jpg" width="711" height="369" alt="Dicks Sporting Goods" title="7"  />
        </div><!--/feature-->
        <div class="count">

        </div>
    </div><!--/dicks-->
```

So what I can manage to get is the overall count of images: x of 7. If I click the slider next button the x never switches. It always stays 1 of 7, 1 of 7, etc...

I'm trying to base this off of a z-index of 3. Orbit assigns that to the img tag when the img is visible. All other images have an index of 1. I'm using the title attribute to give me the 2 of 7, 3 of 7, blah blah.

Any ideas? I am not a JS jedi at all :(

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize your orbit slider, there's an event called `afterSlideChange` which will be called every time the slide changes.

It has no arguments, but the image currently being displayed is used as context (`this`). So you could check it's `index()`, and do something like this:

```
$(function($) {
    $('.featured').orbit({
        afterSlideChange: function() {
            var currentNum = $(this).index() + 1;
            var count = $(this).closest('.featured').find('img').length;
        }
    });    
});
```

How you find where to put the caption is up to what your HTML looks like, but the above should work for finding out the relevant info, every time it changes, in any slideshow.

[Working demo with multiple slideshows](http://jsfiddle.net/stNbW/).

Comment: The only issue with that fix is that I am running 6 orbit sliders on one document. So what it wants to do is make the count 35 (the total number of images within all of the 6 orbits). I need to find a way to make work on each individual instance. Thanks though, this would be the perfect answer if I had only one Orbit instance.

Comment: @Chris: you mentioned in your post that you had the total count figured out already, so I left it at that. The code I've suggested uses a callback that is invoked any time any of the orbits update, so it wouldn't matter how many you create. Anyway, I was wrong about the arguments, though, it seems there are no arguments being passed.  See my updated answer for a solution to that.

Comment: I can see it working is jsfiddle but when I do it, it still fails: http://www.christopherleedesign.com/client/huen/

Comment: Well, for one thing you're using `.featured` in the callback, but the class you're using in your markup is `feature`. Given your markup, another way of finding the label would be to do `$(this).closest('.item').find('.label');` That way you won't need the `dicks-feature` ID or the `dicks-feature-label` class (unless you're using them for something else, of course...

Comment: In short, I think this should fix your problem: `function() { var currentNum = $(this).index() + 1; var count = $(this).closest('.feature').find('img').length; $(this).closest('.item').find('.label').html(currentNum + ' of ' + count); }`

Comment: Wow, I've got this pretty much working. David you are awesome! You should send this thread to Zurb! Do you think there is a way to have it show 1 of 7 before the slideChange event? Or just replace it?

Comment: Just after you've set up the `orbit` call, you could run this code to count the number of images in each orbit and set up the labels: `$('.feature').each(function() { $(this).closest('.item').find('.label').html('1 of ' + $(this).find('img').length); });`

Comment: David, you're awesome! Thank you so much for your help it all worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the triggering event you may beable to use
    $().index(this)

Or otherwise use the index() function.